# Symfony: form_enctype deprecated

Tags: php, symfony

Currently I have following code in symfony 2 and I want to upgrade it to symfony 3. I get this deprecation warning to use `form_start` instead of `form_enctype`. How can I change the following code with `form_start`?

**View:**

```
<form method="post" {{ form_enctype(decryptionForm) }}>
                                {{ form_widget(decryptionForm) }}
                                {{ submit_widget }}
                            </form>
```

**Controller**

```
$form = new DecryptionForm();
        $this->setContext(array(
            'decryptionForm' => $form->createView()
        ));
```

**Form**

```
$builder = $this->getFormBuilder();
        $form = $builder
            ->add(self::FORM_KEY_SAMPLECASE, 'hidden', array())
            ->add(self::FORM_KEY_DECRKEYFILE, 'file', array(
                'constraints' => array(new NotBlank()),
                'label' => "private_key"
            ))
            ->add("Submit", 'submit')
            ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can replace

```
<form method="post" {{ form_enctype(decryptionForm) }}>
```

by

```
{{ form_start(decryptionForm) }}
```

and

```
</form>
```

by

```
{{ form_end(decryptionForm) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Also see [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12333) on GitHub as a reference.

Comment: If you want to add in additional properties to the `<form>` tag, you'll need something like this: `{{ form_start(form, {"attr": {"id": "my-id-here", "class": "custom-class"}}) }}`.

Answer (score 1):

As Alvin mentioned replace form opening and closing to symfony provided functions:
`{{ form_start(decryptionForm) }}` and `{{ form_end(decryptionForm) }}`. Now Symfony handles enctype by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what all else customization your have in your twig file, but it can simple just have this only:

```
{{ form_start(decryptionForm) }}    
{{ form_widget(decryptionForm) }}
{{ form_end(decryptionForm) }}
```

plus extends from your base twig template...